# Plot a bunch of lines in 3D from point data

Tags: list-manipulation, numerics, data, plotting

I have a 12*25 array, wherein each entry is of the form $\{x,y,z\}$. So 12 different $x$ values, 25 different $y$ values and 12*15 $z$ values in all.
I'd like to plot 12 curves of various $x$ values with each curve being a function of $y$. That is something like these two below. In addition, it's better that the original data points are visible and 12 curves can be discernible in terms of $x$ values via color and/or other methods.

[image]

The data :

```
data={{{0.0,0.1,544.5290821},{0.0,0.12,317.9272105},{0.0,0.15,303.7115037},{0.0,0.2,147.8843437},{0.0,0.25,71.16087134},{0.0,0.3,42.01728833},{0.0,0.4,17.04187462},{0.0,0.5,10.47886759},{0.0,0.6,7.087340705},{0.0,0.7,3.865883217},{0.0,0.8,3.026162655},{0.0,0.9,2.577267866},{0.0,1.0,2.006568314},{0.0,1.2,1.187787123},{0.0,1.5,0.7450057751},{0.0,2.0,0.290757454},{0.0,2.5,0.1709376726},{0.0,3.0,0.1015780328},{0.0,4.0,0.03707232976},{0.0,5.0,0.01635099238},{0.0,6.0,0.009965256358},{0.0,7.0,0.006499650839},{0.0,8.0,0.00420646533},{0.0,9.0,0.002955965421},{0.0,10.0,0.002143785229}},{{0.1,0.1,533.4617743},{0.1,0.12,994.4024251},{0.1,0.15,256.836771},{0.1,0.2,128.1365043},{0.1,0.25,74.64665329},{0.1,0.3,36.36893127},{0.1,0.4,25.86592311},{0.1,0.5,11.64411579},{0.1,0.6,6.611596417},{0.1,0.7,4.218899023},{0.1,0.8,2.933009097},{0.1,0.9,2.579442403},{0.1,1.0,1.976079947},{0.1,1.2,1.417675289},{0.1,1.5,0.7065992145},{0.1,2.0,0.03966675362},{0.1,2.5,0.1787197849},{0.1,3.0,0.1108957338},{0.1,4.0,0.03868364847},{0.1,5.0,0.01686629461},{0.1,6.0,0.01057010271},{0.1,7.0,0.006851619379},{0.1,8.0,0.004764092252},{0.1,9.0,0.003150531905},{0.1,10.0,0.002318932646}},{{0.2,0.1,603.3481096},{0.2,0.12,671.0146397},{0.2,0.15,266.6526257},{0.2,0.2,154.9701996},{0.2,0.25,76.57697863},{0.2,0.3,41.26030311},{0.2,0.4,17.28220011},{0.2,0.5,11.35284596},{0.2,0.6,6.831283616},{0.2,0.7,4.54205755},{0.2,0.8,3.217811501},{0.2,0.9,2.73941943},{0.2,1.0,2.165353459},{0.2,1.2,1.353295151},{0.2,1.5,0.7916002866},{0.2,2.0,0.3363254364},{0.2,2.5,0.1930290881},{0.2,3.0,0.1165442108},{0.2,4.0,0.03863095593},{0.2,5.0,0.01770086373},{0.2,6.0,0.01127402615},{0.2,7.0,0.007190122141},{0.2,8.0,0.004553603873},{0.2,9.0,0.003268984244},{0.2,10.0,0.002364645177}},{{0.4,0.1,891.5208123},{0.4,0.12,497.163557},{0.4,0.15,328.7459606},{0.4,0.2,237.3092113},{0.4,0.25,116.5148524},{0.4,0.3,69.0645462},{0.4,0.4,25.47406819},{0.4,0.5,16.05068139},{0.4,0.6,10.33733361},{0.4,0.7,6.475049787},{0.4,0.8,5.896226077},{0.4,0.9,4.002148022},{0.4,1.0,3.086759572},{0.4,1.2,2.010720095},{0.4,1.5,1.106580939},{0.4,2.0,0.4843317016},{0.4,2.5,0.2550470329},{0.4,3.0,0.1677943701},{0.4,4.0,0.05479746563},{0.4,5.0,0.02715589754},{0.4,6.0,0.01620421063},{0.4,7.0,0.01013247822},{0.4,8.0,0.006546351875},{0.4,9.0,0.004427418558},{0.4,10.0,0.003539126809}},{{0.6,0.1,2283.285106},{0.6,0.12,2436.484485},{0.6,0.15,780.620969},{0.6,0.2,369.2014963},{0.6,0.25,264.4490685},{0.6,0.3,140.6140044},{0.6,0.4,71.28059748},{0.6,0.5,29.685109},{0.6,0.6,23.9001713},{0.6,0.7,12.25023497},{0.6,0.8,11.59454174},{0.6,0.9,7.73239968},{0.6,1.0,6.025010196},{0.6,1.2,3.979645325},{0.6,1.5,2.072218022},{0.6,2.0,0.9348596804},{0.6,2.5,0.4809793121},{0.6,3.0,0.3134349187},{0.6,4.0,0.1092997717},{0.6,5.0,0.05180386474},{0.6,6.0,0.03147453316},{0.6,7.0,0.01970144553},{0.6,8.0,0.01274097893},{0.6,9.0,0.009275249842},{0.6,10.0,0.00680813529}},{{0.8,0.1,2693.368219},{0.8,0.12,2219.503399},{0.8,0.15,1228.723357},{0.8,0.2,653.0804944},{0.8,0.25,432.3464167},{0.8,0.3,262.3514466},{0.8,0.4,166.9278694},{0.8,0.5,65.47567947},{0.8,0.6,33.37227577},{0.8,0.7,29.01833466},{0.8,0.8,26.2574645},{0.8,0.9,12.79878997},{0.8,1.0,9.576932293},{0.8,1.2,6.689586323},{0.8,1.5,3.791258328},{0.8,2.0,1.836291366},{0.8,2.5,0.9356165692},{0.8,3.0,0.5667638961},{0.8,4.0,0.1868472718},{0.8,5.0,0.0904072265},{0.8,6.0,0.05096407224},{0.8,7.0,0.03495066575},{0.8,8.0,0.02168385154},{0.8,9.0,0.01517582953},{0.8,10.0,0.01048589866}},{{0.9,0.1,2441.863795},{0.9,0.12,1508.758113},{0.9,0.15,1003.925407},{0.9,0.2,636.5455829},{0.9,0.25,394.4257501},{0.9,0.3,226.1298467},{0.9,0.4,93.89262558},{0.9,0.5,90.49115032},{0.9,0.6,34.22374506},{0.9,0.7,22.46570727},{0.9,0.8,15.75593864},{0.9,0.9,11.69643005},{0.9,1.0,9.573868541},{0.9,1.2,6.800292926},{0.9,1.5,3.609915782},{0.9,2.0,1.569823475},{0.9,2.5,0.8522499462},{0.9,3.0,0.5217609389},{0.9,4.0,0.174272733},{0.9,5.0,0.08668529045},{0.9,6.0,0.04901223217},{0.9,7.0,0.03151505729},{0.9,8.0,0.02154165321},{0.9,9.0,0.01452029402},{0.9,10.0,0.01033995851}},{{1.0,0.1,6084.892374},{1.0,0.12,1917.581591},{1.0,0.15,1055.485222},{1.0,0.2,686.6650971},{1.0,0.25,327.8622258},{1.0,0.3,249.3484563},{1.0,0.4,105.0849315},{1.0,0.5,59.4413843},{1.0,0.6,32.13505206},{1.0,0.7,22.66226696},{1.0,0.8,15.64996264},{1.0,0.9,12.39648073},{1.0,1.0,9.800108007},{1.0,1.2,6.110935535},{1.0,1.5,3.515101855},{1.0,2.0,1.480943061},{1.0,2.5,0.8578045679},{1.0,3.0,0.5082307187},{1.0,4.0,0.1765273188},{1.0,5.0,0.07957088771},{1.0,6.0,0.05013623584},{1.0,7.0,0.02989181163},{1.0,8.0,0.02062943939},{1.0,9.0,0.01508442091},{1.0,10.0,0.01018630915}},{{1.1,0.1,5587.309871},{1.1,0.12,2151.084765},{1.1,0.15,1971.900125},{1.1,0.2,977.0965406},{1.1,0.25,517.1637941},{1.1,0.3,308.2228368},{1.1,0.4,154.2791882},{1.1,0.5,73.1152429},{1.1,0.6,44.59729391},{1.1,0.7,23.85734637},{1.1,0.8,23.71268834},{1.1,0.9,15.15087488},{1.1,1.0,14.15680392},{1.1,1.2,8.630329987},{1.1,1.5,4.794602499},{1.1,2.0,1.957483158},{1.1,2.5,1.104456365},{1.1,3.0,0.6847599086},{1.1,4.0,0.2283797058},{1.1,5.0,0.1067571545},{1.1,6.0,0.0624613694},{1.1,7.0,0.04039668981},{1.1,8.0,0.02580860258},{1.1,9.0,0.01807499314},{1.1,10.0,0.01415569715}},{{1.2,0.1,4164.453439},{1.2,0.12,4545.287862},{1.2,0.15,2421.073664},{1.2,0.2,1226.94888},{1.2,0.25,722.3353724},{1.2,0.3,462.3288227},{1.2,0.4,214.4645374},{1.2,0.5,107.3058066},{1.2,0.6,67.62150917},{1.2,0.7,37.03172479},{1.2,0.8,28.80713612},{1.2,0.9,25.43153706},{1.2,1.0,16.82730276},{1.2,1.2,14.09331035},{1.2,1.5,7.170393913},{1.2,2.0,2.896140096},{1.2,2.5,1.653125217},{1.2,3.0,0.9687954093},{1.2,4.0,0.3162908705},{1.2,5.0,0.151699507},{1.2,6.0,0.09360931908},{1.2,7.0,0.06019528083},{1.2,8.0,0.03762907646},{1.2,9.0,0.02811320466},{1.2,10.0,0.0198520522}},{{1.4,0.1,8236.314655},{1.4,0.12,4836.300897},{1.4,0.15,2098.945446},{1.4,0.2,1716.251498},{1.4,0.25,830.9983541},{1.4,0.3,499.7441392},{1.4,0.4,231.8145463},{1.4,0.5,121.8951661},{1.4,0.6,72.26179255},{1.4,0.7,69.11735894},{1.4,0.8,43.48609849},{1.4,0.9,37.19931242},{1.4,1.0,23.24327713},{1.4,1.2,14.24973452},{1.4,1.5,8.564273083},{1.4,2.0,3.577710864},{1.4,2.5,1.889226696},{1.4,3.0,1.134167819},{1.4,4.0,0.3802416305},{1.4,5.0,0.1985214906},{1.4,6.0,0.1092341444},{1.4,7.0,0.07047733105},{1.4,8.0,0.04816233404},{1.4,9.0,0.03156027608},{1.4,10.0,0.02407256048}},{{1.6,0.1,29.52066924},{1.6,0.12,22.71601945},{1.6,0.15,30.84142768},{1.6,0.2,13.77066818},{1.6,0.25,8.060411067},{1.6,0.3,4.741210292},{1.6,0.4,2.338522635},{1.6,0.5,1.945226175},{1.6,0.6,1.225388715},{1.6,0.7,1.014778098},{1.6,0.8,0.7835036175},{1.6,0.9,0.6338702535},{1.6,1.0,0.4735900446},{1.6,1.2,0.3054580288},{1.6,1.5,0.1598250625},{1.6,2.0,0.0573159134},{1.6,2.5,0.02839756906},{1.6,3.0,0.01880761962},{1.6,4.0,0.008210913309},{1.6,5.0,0.003957314909},{1.6,6.0,0.00192907335},{1.6,7.0,0.001438041179},{1.6,8.0,0.0008386913523},{1.6,9.0,0.0006333051914},{1.6,10.0,0.0004062951405}}};
```

Comment: Does this do what you want, ListPointPlot3D[data] /. Point -> Line?

Comment: @Algohi would you consider answering?

Comment: @YvesKlett, Done. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ListPointPlot3D[data, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0.02], Thickness[0.01]]] /. 
 Point[x_] -> Through[{Point, Line}[x]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using `ListPlot3D` with `Mesh`:

```
data = Table[{i, j, Sin[j^2 + i]}, {j, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/11}, {i, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/24}];
Dimensions[data]
(* {12, 25, 3} *)

colors = Directive[Thick, #] & /@ ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Range[0, 1, 1/11];

lp3d = ListPlot3D[Join @@ data, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.3], BoundaryStyle -> None,
  Mesh -> {0, Thread[{Range[0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/11], colors}]}]
```

[image]

```
Show[ListPlot3D[Join @@ data, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.3], BoundaryStyle -> None, 
  Mesh -> {0, Thread[{Range[0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/11], colors}]}], 
 ListPointPlot3D[data, PlotStyle -> colors], BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can post-process `Line`s in the `ListPlot3D` output into `Point`s and `Line`s to get the same picture:

```
lp3d /. Line[x__] :> {PointSize[Large], Point@x, Line@x}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
d = data /. {x_Real, y_Real, z_Real} -> {{x, y}, z};
dat = Flatten[d, 1];
int = Interpolation[dat];

Plot3D[int[x, y], {x, 0, 1.6}, {y, 0.1, 10},
 Mesh -> {data[[All, 1]][[All, 1]], data[[1, All]][[All, 2]]},
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5], MeshStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

[image]

The idea is to use Mesh option for drowing lines on surface obtained from multidimentional interpolation of your data